# .NET Core 2.0 application published as deb file

Tags: .net, ubuntu, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to transform published .NET Core 2.0 application to .deb file? 
I published my app by `dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64`. Now, my goal is to have a deb file that can be installed on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: You dont need *.deb. Just copy publish folder and run app by `dotnet yourapp`

Answer (score 27):

If you want to create a `.deb` package for your .NET Core application, you can use `dotnet-deb`.

To install `dotnet-deb`, add the following references to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Packaging.Targets" Version="0.1.1-*" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-deb" Version="0.1.1-*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then, run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet publish -c Release -f netcoreapp2.0 -r ubuntu.16.04-x64`. This will generate a Debian installer package for you.

I'm the  maintainer for the `dotnet-deb`, feel free to ask follow up questions or head over to https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging! It provides commands like `dotnet deb` to package up your project into a deb/rpm/tar for Linux.