# How to build a .deb package with ElectronNet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, electron

I'm using ElectronNet to build a cross-platform app, I need to create a .deb package to distribute the application.

- ElectronNet: 5.22.14
- ElectronNet.Cli: 9.31.2

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809219/net-core-2-0-application-published-as-deb-file

Comment: Yes, but the command to use is electronize to create an electron application. I cant build using a traditional way.

Comment: @LucasFerla ever figure this out?