# How to create .deb file for .NET core project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, deb, avaloniaui

I have created a desktop application using Avalonia UI. It is a cross-platform framework and I want to create .deb file which can install and run on Linux os.

Comment: did you try to search for `create deb`?

Comment: First hit after this question : https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-deb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 2.0 application published as deb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809219/net-core-2-0-application-published-as-deb-file) (If not, let us know)

Comment: @Fildor After installing that What should I do

Comment: @TimothyP It didn't work